# For official Maven repositories do people release fat jars?

Tags: java, maven

I want to deploy a Java application to a Maven repository, and I am unsure if I should release the fat `jar` or `jar` w/o dependencies.

I checked junit's example (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12) and they  have a `jar` file that is only 307 KB.

Do people release the fat `jar` or `jar` without dependencies?

Comment: Releasing a fat jar on a Maven repository would really be a big no in almost all cases I can think of. And the cases where it might be sensible, you would have to ask yourself if that would be something that needs to be released to a Maven repository.

Comment: fat jars would be an *alternative* to a Maven dependency that you could provide for those not using Maven / Gradle. You wouldn't put it in Maven directly.

Comment: Please, please, please don't.  If you provide your artifact with dependencies I can manipulate them in my own pom (standard example:  I don't like your choice of slf4j backend) instead of having to jump through hoops.

Comment: @berry120 and putting fat jars in Maven for those who don't use Maven may not have that much of an impact :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're releasing to Maven central, then your first option should be to release your artifact with just its code. This should not be a problem as a typical user downloading from Maven central will be systematically using the Maven tooling, which takes the complexity away from the user.

Unless the artifact is intended to be an executable with all dependencies, such that the user would just run it after downloading, there are few benefits to publishing a fat jar, set against a mountain of drawbacks.

If you are publishing a "library" with code to be used in other applications:

- A single artifact with its POM allows your users to select what they include of your transitive dependencies
- A single artifact makes it easy to resolve conflicts (it's easy to identify which jar a given class comes from)
- A single artifact allows your users to have visibility over the actual dependency tree

Answer (score 3):

Applications are typically not published to Maven repositories as you don't usually add full applications as a dependency to you project. For libraries it doesn't make sense to include their dependencies into the jar if they are available though maven central them self, because Maven can just download them and as Ernest Kiwele mentions in his answer it provides more flexibility to the downstream projects.